# excel vba Protect Password method

Tags: excel, vba

I recently took over a excel vba project, but I found there is a line code written as below:

```
thisWs = Worksheets("Sheet1")
`pwd1 = "123" 
 thisWs.Protect Password:=pwd1`
```

I have no idea what "Protect Password" is, is that a method or property?

Comment: Did you google [worksheet.protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) ?

Comment: Please keep in mind that SO is intended to help programmers solve their programming problems and should not be used to simply forego trying to solve the problem on your own. That being said...in this case thisws is likely "ThisWorksheet" and ".Protect" is a method of that object whereby it "Protects" the sheet using the supplied password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Protect' is a method of the Worksheet class.

'Password' is a parameter of this function that is being passed.

Microsoft documentation defines this.

Comment: shouldn't it be written like "thisws.Protect(Password)"?

Comment: Answers consisting of a link belong to the comments section.

Comment: In most languages yes, but in VBA, this is completely legitimate. The reason is that the ':=' tells the compiler that 'Password' is a parameter, while letting you set the parameter value to the variable 'pwd1' that you have.